# Get category name in php / xml feed in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

We are looking for a way to get the product name in a product feed in Magento. We get the data and then run the loop to get the products, we only do not get the category names and subcategory names.

Does anybody know how to get them?

Hereby a part of the code to make the xml from a php:

[image]

Comment: provide some code to make it more clear.

Comment: In the image you see a part of the code. In the part //Echo run the loop, the xml is made, but we do not know how to get there the categories and subcategories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<categories>
    <?php $categoryCollection = $product->getCategoryCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name');?>
    <?php foreach($categoryCollection as $cat): ?>
        <cat><?php echo $cat->getName() == null ? '' : $cat->getName(); ?></cat>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</categories>
```

P.S. I would use magento's resource iterator to walk the collection so not to run into memory issues when running the script. Check out http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/loading-large-collections for an example of this.

Comment: Ashley, I tried your code and have also placed a new picture where you can see where I placed the code, but at this moment he does not return anything so the field subcategories is empty. Do I do something wrong?

Comment: Try this;

<categories><?php $categoryCollection = $product->getCategoryCollection();?><?php foreach($categoryCollection as $cat): ?><subcat><?php echo $cat->getId(); ?></subcat><?php endforeach; ?></categories>

Comment: That's good. Try changing to this now; $categoryCollection = $product->getCategoryCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name'); and then you should be able to call getName() on the $cat object.

Comment: I think that is almost it. I get one more error This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1645 at column 45: xmlParseEntityRef: no name
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Comment: Is there a way when there is no name to still show, or not show a name at that spot?

Comment: I just placed your last comment in there, but still get the same error. The main image is just replaced, so you can see how the code looks like by now.

Comment: Xml Parse Error. Sounds like invalid xml being generated not a code issue. Maybe a category names contains an '&' or some other html entity that needs to be encoded. Try calling htmlentities($cat->getName()). Please accept my answer for your question.

Comment: Ashley, thats it so great work and I will accept your answer!

Comment: I want one more thing, but I placed it in a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050606/magento-get-main-and-subcategories-in-php-xml-feed, if you know the answer let me know there!

Answer (score 0):

```
function getCategoryTree( $parent = 0, $recursionLevel = 1 )
{
    if($parent == 0){
        $parent = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
    }else{
    $parent = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parent)->getId();
    }
     $tree = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_tree');
    /* @var $tree Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Tree */
    $nodes = $tree->loadNode($parent)
        ->loadChildren($recursionLevel)
        ->getChildren();
    $tree->addCollectionData(null, false, $parent);
    $json = array('success' => true);
    $result = array();
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        $result[] = array(
            'category_id'   => $node->getData('entity_id'),
            'parent_id'     => $parent,
            'name'          => $node->getName(),
            'categories'    => getNodeChildrenData($node));
    }
    $json['categories'] = $result;
    return $json;
}
```

https://github.com/app-z/magento-android-web-api